# Why does writing to a read-only register increase current consumption?

Tags: microcontroller, current, msp430, vlsi

Looking at the datasheet of the MSP430, it says writing to read-only registers results in increased current consumption. [image: MSP430 Datasheet screenshot]

Why is that? What is happening when trying to write to a read-only section of memory that increases current consumption?
For reference, here is the [family datasheet for the MPS430](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf).

Edit: Further, are there other devices that exhibit similar behavior? It seems like I've seen this in datasheets before, but maybe not.

Comment: This probably can only be answered by speculation.  They key point is that they are implicitly telling you not to do it.

Comment: That's a funny thing. So instead of throwing some kind of failure or ignoring the attempt they are doing some stuff which is increasing the current consumption... I would call it a major bug in the design.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That was my thoughts exactly. I would normally expect a device to just ignore the write, but I was surprised to read that it _increases_ current consumption.

Comment: Maybe try reading it then writing back the exact same value to see if it is clash of logic levels for each bit? Then try inverting the read value to see if it gets worse.

Comment: I think the key wording is "while the write attempt is active".  Seems like it might spin its wheels for a while and then time out.  You could test this by timing writes to a read only register versus writes to a writeable register.

Comment: Just so people are on the same page, which exact MSP430 is this? Can you give a link to this document?

Comment: Are you able to measure the current?  Does It increase more so than a write to RW registers?  Maybe that note is the result of a pedantic tech writer that thinks it is important for you to know that you use more current to write than if you do not write, and thus, since RO registers need not be written, you can "save" current(?)  I dunno really, pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

All the other GPIO registers are writable, so I guess somebody just copied+pasted this part of the hardware design, and did not bother to remove the write access.

The PxIN register always shows the current value at the pin. This implies that the register is continuously updated, i.e., the pin always *writes* to the register.

If you try to write from the CPU, both the CPU and the pin try to write at the same time, which means that both try to drive the same signal as the same time. And if you connect two active driver outputs with opposite levels together, you get a short between V<sub>CC</sub> and ground. (This short is only for a clock cycle, and through two MOSFETs that do not need to have a low R<sub>DS(on)</sub>, so it's apparently not very harmful.)